# Scheme - define variable as the result of a function?

Tags: function, functional-programming, scheme

The beginning of one of my programs results in an error.  This is the problem area.  I am trying to define a variable as the result of a recursive function.

```
(define (test n)
  (define (a1func i)
    (if (= i 1) 0
        (+ (/ 1 i) (a1func (- i 1))))) 
  (define a1 (a1func (- n 1))))
```

if you were to give it say `(test 10)` the error would be:

> procedure application: expected procedure, given: `#<undefined>`; arguments were: 9

I assumed this could be done in Scheme??  ideas?

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Can you post the rest?

Comment: BTW, your code's missing a closing `)` in the end of the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure FP languages computations are done passing parameters to functions, which return some values as a result. You could bind the result of `test` in the function which called `test`:

```
(define (test n)
  (define (a1func i)
    (if (= i 1) 0
        (+ (/ 1 i) (a1func (- i 1))))) 
  (a1func (- n 1)))

(define (calltest x)
  (define (r (test (+ 2 x))))
  (- r 4))
```

Variables usually bound once and cannot be changed. A function must return the value, a result of expression, but `(define a1 (a1func(- n 1)))` is rather a definition, not an expression, so the correct code would be:

```
(define (test n)
  (define (a1func i)
    (if (= i 1) 0
        (+(/ 1 i) (a1func(- i 1))))) 
  (define a1 (a1func(- n 1)))
  a1)
```

And since defining variable and immediate returning it is meaningless, a more correct code would be:

```
(define (test n)
  (define (a1func i)
    (if (= i 1) 0
        (+(/ 1 i) (a1func(- i 1))))) 
  (a1func(- n 1)))
```

Comment: problem being is that I need a1 bound to the resulting value of a1func.  I am using the value a1 later in the program, as well as variable n (original input).

Comment: Then you should define `a1` in top of your module, because in your original definition `a1` is in the scope of the function `test`, otherwise no other function is able to use it. If you define `a1` in the top of your module, you should then define `a1func` the same way, so that it's accessible outside of the scope of `test`.

Comment: I'm gonna take another stab at this.. and I'm not sure why I'm having such issues.  So I'm starting from the beginning again..  I have a program that takes a value n.  This program than has to run through several mathematical operations.  some of those operations use values from earlier operations.  ex.    (define (a1func1 n)
   (let* ((e1 0))
   (let* ((i (- n 1)))
        (if (= n 1) 0
      (+(/ 1 i) (a1func1(- n 1))))))) ...  I get the correct result, but need it stored globally.  to use in several later functions.

Comment: @DJPlayer: In FP you don't usually store variables globally, a functional program is just a series of [mutual] calls to functions, when each function performs some calculations on given parameters and returns the result. You should get to idea that a function always returns *the same* result if you give it the same parameters, e. g. if you give it `2`, `3` and it calculates a sum, it will always return `5`, irrespective of number of calls to it. You may have global variables (using `define`), but they cannot be changed (if we're talking about pure FP).

Answer (score 0):

If your scheme implementation support lisp macros then you can write this:

```
(define-macro (test n)
  (define (a1func i)
    (if (= i 1) 0
        (+ (/ 1 i) (a1func (- i 1)))))  
  `(define a1 ,(a1func (- n 1))))
```

or using named let

```
(define-macro (test n)
  `(define a1 ,(let a1func ((i (- n 1)))
                 (if (= i 1)
                     0
                     (+ (/ 1 i) (a1func (- i 1)))))))
```