# storing values in Scheme globally

Tags: scheme

I have a series of mathmetical operations I need to perform.  The input of the function is n.

the first two operations are summations.  using n.  The result needs stored as a variable to be used in later functions.

ex.

```
main func(n)
       func1 (n)
         returns a1

       func2 (n)
         returns b1

       func4 
         uses b1 to compute c1

       etc....
```

I've created all the functions sepearted but need to use a main function that merely takes in n, and a way to store the variables globally for use in later functions (without changing them).  these are the first 2 functions.

```
(define (main n)
 (define (a1func n)
   (let* ((a1 0))
   (let* ((i (- n 1)))
        (if (= n 1) 0
      (+(/ 1 i) (a1func(- n 1)))))))

 (define (a2func n)
   (let ((a2 0))
   (let ((i (- n 1)))
   (if (= n 1) 0
        (+(/ 1 (expt i 2)) (a2func(- n 1)))))))

  (define b1 
    (if (= n 1) 0
        (/(+ n 1)(* 3(- n 1))))) 
  (define b2 
    (if (= n 1) 0
        (/(* 2 (+ n 3 (expt n 2))) (*(- n 1)(* 9 n)))))
  (define c1 (- b1 (/ 1 a1)))   
  (define c2 (+ (- b2 (/ (+ n 2) (* a1 n))) (/ a2 (expt a1 2))))
  (define e1 (/ c1 a1))
  (define e2 (/ c2 (+ (expt a1 2) a2)))
  (list e1 e2))
```

Comment: This question is a reworded continuation of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4801595/298282

Comment: I didn't feel I properly explained myself in the original.. also I posted my entire code (vs just a snippet of it) to demonstrate exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functional programming is different from imperative programming. Scheme is a functional language. Do not use bound variables as memory locations. But if you need something like memory locations then use vector.

If you want to use the value of variable in another functior then pass it to that function as a parameter:

```
(define (fun1 n) ...)
(define (fun2 n) ...)
(define (fun4 n b) ...)

(define (main n)
  (let ((a1 (fun1 n))
        (b1 (fun2 n)))
    (let ((c1 (fun4 n b1)))
      ( .....)))...))))
```

Comment: yup this was sorta how I got it done.  I used two separate helper-functions to get my a1 and a2.  I then used a completely separate function to do the rest of the work (calling my two helper functions within).  I think my error was trying to use defines within eachoher.  Especially when two of those fuctions were recursive.  Scheme certainly takes a different mindset than OOP.

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way to make a function compute result using the output of another function is *composition*. In the following example, you want `add2` to work on the result of `add1` and achieve that by *composing* the functions:

```
> (define (add1 n) (+ 1 n))
> (define (add2 n) (+ 2 n))

> (add2 (add1 10))
=> 13
```

If you really want to work with global state, you can do that with the help of closures so that the global namespace itself is not spoiled:

```
(define (make-adder n)
  (lambda (msg)
    (case msg
      ((one) 
       (set! n (+ 1 n)))       
      ((two) 
       (set! n (+ 2 n))))
    n))


> (define adder (make-adder 10))
> (adder 'one)
11
> (adder 'two)
13
```